# Creating table with counter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code and am trying to get the number entered by the user to create that amount of rows with a counter in the cells up to the number entered(ie. if user enters 6, 6 rows will appear with 1-6 in them, 1 at the top)  I figure a for-loop would work well, but I can't figure out what variables work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#nbrTxt').focus();

  var index = 1;
  $('input[name=nbrTxt]').on('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.which === 13) {
      $('table').append('<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>');
      $('table tr:last td:first').html($(this).val());
      $('table tr:last td:last').html(index);
      $(this).focus().select();
      index++;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<title> JQuery Selector</title>

<style type="text/css"> 

body {
  font-family:  Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
   
}

</style>

<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="jqueryselector.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

  <h1>JQuery Selector</h1>

Enter Number: 
<input type="number" name= "nbrTxt" id="nbrTxt" />
<input type="button" value="GO" id="btnGo"/>

  <table id="table" width="500" border="1">
  <tr>
   <td>No. Count</td>
 <td>Name</td>
  </tr>
</table>
  
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. I just changed keyup event to click though, but it should work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#nbrTxt').focus();

  $('#btnGo').on('click', function(e) {
        var value = $('#nbrTxt').val();

      for (var i = 1; i <= value; i++) {
          $('table').append('<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>');
          $('table tr:last td:first').html(value);
          $('table tr:last td:last').html(i);
      }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a for loop.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#nbrTxt').focus();

  $('input[name=nbrTxt]').on('keyup', function(e) {
    var index = parseInt($(this).val());

    if (e.which === 13) {
      for(var i = 1; i <= index; i++) {
        $('table').append('<tr><td>' + i + '</td><td></td></tr>');
        $(this).focus().select();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<title> JQuery Selector</title>

<style type="text/css"> 

body {
  font-family:  Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
   
}

</style>

<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="jqueryselector.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

  <h1>JQuery Selector</h1>

Enter Number: 
<input type="number" name= "nbrTxt" id="nbrTxt" />
<input type="button" value="GO" id="btnGo"/>

  <table id="table" width="500" border="1">
  <tr>
   <td>No. Count</td>
 <td>Name</td>
  </tr>
</table>
  
</body>
```